# Print/append to list the value of threaded function in order threading module

Tags: python, multithreading

I try to get data from links (using urllib) and print it in order (the data from the first link first, the data from the second link 2st etc..) Of course, without threads that works well and prints it in the correct order, but when I do it with threading it disrupts the order and could not figure out how to fix it
Here is my code: Thanks!!

```
def with_threading():
    def run(num, q):
        q.put(urllib2.urlopen("%s" % str(num)).read())

    start_time = time.time()
    q = Queue.Queue()
    movies_names_list = []

    threads_list = [threading.Thread(target=run, args=(i, q)) for i in xrange(1, 33)]

    for thread in threads_list:
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads_list:
        thread.join()

    for i in xrange(1, 33):
        movies_names_list.append(q.get())

    print movies_names_list
    print "\nElapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start_time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by marking each movie with additional index before putting it in the Queue and then sort the results:

```
def with_threading():
    def run(num, q):
        q.put(((urllib2.urlopen("%s" % str(num)).read()), num))

    start_time = time.time()
    q = Queue.Queue()
    movies_names_list = []

    threads_list = [threading.Thread(target=run, args=(i, q)) for i in xrange(1, 33)]

    for thread in threads_list:
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads_list:
        thread.join()

    for i in xrange(1, 33):
        movies_names_list.append(q.get())

    res = sorted(movies_names_list, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
    res = [item[0] for item in res]
    print res
    print "\nElapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start_time)
```